# Is it good practice to always remove highly correlated variables?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, correlation, encoding

1- Would it always be beneficial to remove highly correlated features prior to training a model? If not, why not.

2- Would you perform One Hot encoding where applicable, prior to removing highly correlated features ? (taking into account a dummy variable may be highly correlated with another variable)

Thanks

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/50583/196987

Answer (score 2):

(1) **No**. For example, if you have computer vision problems, then each pixel of the image is a feature. most neighboring pixels are highly correlated.

For example, see the following image from [The HASYv2 dataset](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08380.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Interesting. How about for classification/regression algorithms such as xgboost, random forest etc ?

Comment: I haven't executed a comparative analysis of the performance of different classifiers with vs without the removal of highly correlated features. Only for CNNs on Computer Vision tasks I know for sure that you don't want to remove highly correlated features.